# Enable AWS Security Hub with CloudFormation Templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-hub

The [CloudFormation documentation for Security Hub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-securityhub-hub.html) is very limited.
I wonder if it is possible to do the following in **CloudFormation**

1. **Enable Security Hub in specified accounts or all accounts for an
   organization**.
   *There’s a sample script to automate enabling Security Hub for multiple accounts but no CloudFormation implementation can be found:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-enable.html#securityhub-enable-multiaccount-script*
2. **Enable finding aggregation**
   *It seems you can enable finding aggregation using console, CLI or API:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/finding-aggregation-enable.html*
3. **Specify Delegated Administrator by account id**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do all these things through a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation in the form of a lambda function.